# RxJava: AssertError on TestObserver not asserting true when expection thrown

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I am testing real API Calls with Retrofit as following:

```
@Test
public void getList(){
    TestObserver<MyResponse> testObserver = api
            .getResults(params)
            .lift(apiErrorOperator)
            .lift(emptyResponseOperator)
            .test();
    testObserver.awaitTerminalEvent();
    testObserver.assertError(ApiException.class);
}
```

The test fails with these 2 errors:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: onSubscribe not called in proper order
```

and

```
Caused by: com.example.myapplication.repository.ApiException: Search found 0 results
```

The second makes sense, since this is the behaviour I am expecting. However, I do not understand why `testObserver.assertError(ApiException.class)` is not returning true, and why I get the first error too.

For the first error, this line `java.lang.IllegalStateException: onSubscribe not called in proper order` is thrown at this line `observer.onError(new ApiException("Search found 0 results"))` from `emptyResponseOperator`. Below is code for full class:

```
public class EmptyResponseOperator implements ObservableOperator<MyResponse, MyResponse> {
    @Override
    public Observer<? super MyResponse> apply(Observer<? super MyResponse> observer) throws Exception {
        return new DisposableObserver<MyResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onNext(MyResponse myResponse) {
                if(myResponse.getTotalResultsCount() == 0)
                    observer.onError(new ApiException("Search found 0 results"));
                else{
                    observer.onNext(myResponse);
                    observer.onComplete();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                observer.onError(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                observer.onComplete();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And also here is the code for ApiErrorOperator class:

```
public class ApiErrorOperator<T> implements ObservableOperator<T, Response<T>> {


    @Override
    public Observer<? super Response<T>> apply(Observer<? super T> observer) throws Exception {
        return new DisposableObserver<Response<T>>() {
            @Override
            public void onNext(Response<T> tResponse) {
                if(!tResponse.isSuccessful()){
                    try {
                        if (tResponse.errorBody() != null) {
                            observer.onError(new ApiException(tResponse.errorBody().string()));
                        }else{
                            observer.onError(new ApiException(C.ERROR_UNKNOWN));
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        observer.onError(new ApiException(C.ERROR_IO));
                    }
                }
                else if (tResponse.body() == null) {
                    observer.onError(new ApiException(C.ERROR_NOT_FOUND));
                }else{
                    observer.onNext(tResponse.body());
                    observer.onComplete();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                observer.onError(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                observer.onComplete();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a protocol violation in your code as you don't call `onSubscribe` when you chain `Observer`s, among other issues that can bite you later. We don't recommend implementing custom behavior this way. We have [documentation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Writing-operators-for-2.0#creating-operator-classes) in case you want to do it anyways.

Comment: @akarnokd Please, could you explain further? I don't quite understand what you mean with chaining Observers, and with the protocol violation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't recommend writing custom behavior this way. You have to follow the Observable protocol, like this:

```java
public class EmptyResponseOperator implements ObservableOperator<MyResponse, MyResponse> {
    @Override
    public Observer<? super MyResponse> apply(Observer<? super MyResponse> observer)
    throws Exception {
        return new DisposableObserver<MyResponse>() {

            // -------------------------------------
            // vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                observer.onSubscribe(this);
            }
            // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            // -------------------------------------

            @Override
            public void onNext(MyResponse myResponse) {
                dispose(); // <-------------------------------------------------------
                if (myResponse.getTotalResultsCount() == 0) {
                    observer.onError(new ApiException("Search found 0 results"));
                } else {
                    observer.onNext(myResponse);
                    observer.onComplete();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                if (!isDisposed()) {   // <---------------------------------------
                    observer.onError(e);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                if (!isDisposed()) {   // <---------------------------------------
                    observer.onComplete();
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, much appreciated. I think I need to read the wiki to understand this better. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation is wrong, and try to avoid chain travels downstream in your code.

check below sample and go through documentation here.

```
 Single.just(1)
    .delaySubscription(Completable.create(new CompletableOnSubscribe() {
        @Override
        public void subscribe(CompletableEmitter e) throws Exception {
            if (!e.isDisposed()) {
                e.onError(new TestException());
            }
        }
    }))
    .test()
    .assertFailure(TestException.class);
```

-- `onSubscribe` wires them up and there you go.

Another solution

create custom operator. [How?](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Writing-operators-for-2.0#operator-by-extending-a-base-reactive-class)

Comment: Could you explain what you mean with chain traveling downstreams, please?